# POST Request For jsonp Response in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, post, jsonp

I'm developing an HTML5 Application.
In my application, there is one page for posting the user comments.There is a submit button.
I'm getting the following set of values {BrandId,ForumId,Title,Description}, which needs to be appended with url string for POST Request.
In my submit method,I have written code for ajax POST call as,

```
 $.ajax({  
        type:"POST",        
        url: "myURL",  // the appended url with above 4 values
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        success: function(result)
        { 
           alert("success in posting data");
         } 

    });
```

But this is not showing "success".
Can anyone guide me to successfully implement post request for posting the data to the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you passing the post values? You need to add them in ajax data: property.

Comment: Are you posting to the same domain your website originates from? I ask, because you've set dataType to 'jsonp', which would suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit your data by appending them to your url, you need to do a get request.

If you want to use a post request like in your exemple, you need to tell the ajax function which data to send